# Use DLL static variable in different threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, threadpool

I have an ASP.Net WebAPI (MVC) served by IIS Express which uses an external dll library.
This library is unfortunately built to have only one client, this means it has a static variable "Client" it uses everywhere.

So if i have many clients, for each request i have to switch this static variable to the client that did the request.
The problem is that this way, i need to "lock" the variable, and therefore not allow other clients to request.

I don't know exactly the way IIS manages its threads with the thread pool, but i think it should be something like one thread per request. So putting this "Client" variable to ThreadStatic could do the job since its value would be different for each thread, but since "Client" is used in intern threads of the library, it should generate lot of bugs.

To explain more precisely what i want, consider this situation :

You have a piece of code like that, which represents my library :

```
class Client {
     void doSomething() {}
     void blabla() {}
}

static Client c;

... Code here, probably involving c in threads ...

public void function() {
     c.blabla();
}
```

And in my application, i have multiple threads which want to call doSomething(), and function() at the same time. So they need to "trick" the compiler to create a local variable and put it in the 'c' variable.
Hope it helps.

Comment: You would have to modify the DLL's IL to add the attribute, so that when the JITter compiles the code, it knows what to do. You're not going to be able to change the nature of the variable after the fact. _"This library is unfortunately built to have only one client...i have many clients"_ -- there's your problem. Use a different library, or even re-implement the functionality yourself. The library you're using just wasn't build to support your scenario.

Comment: If you really _must_ use this library, one option might be to create an AppDomain for each client. This is _very_ heavyweight though; it will only scale so far, and if "many clients" means 100 or more, I doubt it would work. You'd probably start running into trouble at the dozen or two mark, I'd guess.

Comment: Actually this library is about 1M lines and is professional (my job is to create a web interface for them). I already thought about AppDomains, and as you mentioned, impossible with the memory it needs after only 30 or 40 clients.

Comment: _"my job is to create a web interface for them"_ -- if they are your client, you should work with them to address the limitation. There's not enough context in your question to know what specifically needs to be changed, but they're the ones who painted you into the corner. They should help you get back out. Barring that, maybe instead of AppDomains, just run one process per client; in theory that should be _worse_ than AppDomains, but you might avoid some marshaling overhead and Windows might do a better job of partitioning the work than .NET does. Just a thought, might not be worth anything.

Comment: It's not my client, i work in the company ! I know the code of this library, i can modify it. But putting a ThreadStatic on this field would be catastrophic since it is used in many threads through the code. And i don't want to change a so important field just for a web interface. I'll try the process separation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Your original question was _"how to dynamically put a variable on ThreadStatic?"_. I took that to mean you were unable to apply the attribute directly in code, but only because you did not have access to the code. Now, you seem to be saying you _do_ have access to the code and can modify it, but don't want to because doing so would be "catastrophic". If you believe it would be catastrophic to apply the attribute directly, why do you think it would help to do the same thing, only "dynamically"?

Comment: You're right, the problem is a bit more precise. On my webapi, i want to use the code provided by my library (which probably use threads too), but with a Client dependant to the thread i use. I just want to "trick" the system to have "multiple" static variables, one per thread. Perhaps ThreadStatic is not the solution, because as you mentionned it impacts ALL the threads, including those in the library itself. I hope i'm clear.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty broad architectural problem that you and your coworkers are going to have to work out together. I doubt Stack Overflow is going to be able to help, not without a much more specific and detailed question, that includes a good [mcve] and a clear description of all applicable constraints and requirements.

Comment: Post edited. The problem i have with my coworker is not very interesting here, no ? Just try to solve the problem, and if it's not enough explicit, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer changed in the light of the first comment)

I would just lock all access and do one thing at a time.

If that's not good enough, I would argue it's good enough.

Then I would see if I can queue the work.

Then I would look into reflection `System.Reflection.LoadAssembly`, but after reading  [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading) (from 2017-03-30). :)

Comment: Because my library don't use the method "GetClient()" you create, it uses "Client" everywhere, and Client is created somewhere at initialisation IN the library, so i can't (or exactly i don't want to) modify it.

Comment: Ah. I understand now.

Comment: Haha that's not good enough ;) my requests are asking for large amounts of data treatment, which takes about 4 or 5 seconds. So imagine if i have 100 clients at the same time ... I'll take a look at the Reflection, seems interesting.

Comment: 1. Would you have 100 clients? 2. Can you queue?

Comment: 1. Definitely possible.    2. Queue ? I can, but it would lead to a long wait ...

Comment: What about: accept, queue, return, process in the background?

Comment: @FaZeGa my idea is to create a pool of workers - appdomains or separate processes, that will process the queue. That's how you'll avoid a heavy cost of creating new AppDomains/Processes, but also you'll get good enough relatively scalable parallel processing

Comment: By return i assume wait for new requests ? Then when you got a new request, it means a new client and so you can't process anything since the "Client" variable is locked.

Comment: @OlehNechytailo actually a nice idea !

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research i conclude that the only (and logical) way is to create AppDomains or separate processes.
I'll perhaps follow the @OlehNechytailo suggestion.